# Exercise about max and min of a 2D function with absolute value

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I haven't done an exercise like this so, please, tell me if the proceeding is wrong and any kind of observations that you think can help me.

> Find global max and min of $$f(x,y)=|x^2-y|$$
>
> in the subset contained in the region of the square that has verteces in
>   (1,-1),(-1, 1),(-1,-1), (1,1) and delimited by $y=-1$ and $y=x^2$.

I have proceeded in the following way:

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}x^2-y || if (y> x^2)\\y-x^2 ||if( y\leq x^2)(*)\end{cases}$$

The region that I have to analyse is under the parabola, so I can analyse only (*).

I'm going to look for critical point inner to the region:

$$\begin{cases}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-2x=0\\\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=1\neq 0\end{cases}$$

So there aren't critical point inner to the region.

I'm going to look for them **on the parabola**:
$f_{|parabola}=y-x^2=0$ 
So the points $(x,x^2)$ are *all* critical points.  I have to determine if they are max or min, so:

$\Delta f=f(x,y)-f(x,x^2)=|x^2-y|$ and it is >0 because it is an absolute value. So $(x,x^2)$ are min.

Now I'm going to look for critical points **on the segment AB** (A=(-1, -1), B=(1, -1))

$$f_{AB}= |x^2+1|=\begin {cases}x^2+1 || if (x^2 \geq-1)(**)\\ -1-x^2|| if(x^2<-1)\end{cases} $$

the second case is impossible, so I can study only (**):

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x$ Criticl point for x=0 so, $P=(0,-1)$ is a point of minimum and $f(0,-1)=1$.

Now I have to analyse the extremes of the segment to find the max:
$f(A)=f(-1,-1)=2$ and $f(B)=f(1,-1)=2$, so they are max.

Now I'm going to search for critical points **on the segment AC** (A=(-1,-1), C=(-1,1)):

$f_{|AC}=|1-y|=\begin{cases} 1-y|| if (y \leq 1)(***)\\y-1|| if (y>1)\end{cases}$

But on the AC segment, $-1 \leq y\leq 1$, so I can analise only (***):

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-1 \neq 0$

So there aren't critical points on the segment; I'm looking for them on the extremes of the segment:

f(A)=2; f(B)=2.

For them we have: $\Delta f=f(x,y)-f(A)=1-y-2=-y-1$. But on the segment, we have $-1 \leq y\leq 1$, so $\Delta f  \in [-2,0]$, so A, B are max.

Now I'm searching for critical points **on the segment BD** (B=(1, -1), D=(1,1)).

$f_{|BD}=|1-y|=1-y$ (as we said for previous case).

There aren't critical points on the segment and the B-extreme is a max. 
For the point D: f(D)=0, $\Delta f=1-y-0=1-y$, so (on the BC segment) $\Delta f \in [0,2]$, so D is a min (it doesn't contraddict the previous result $(x, x^2)$ are min).

**In conclusion**,

- global max: (-1, -1) and (1, -1)
- global min: $(x, x^2)$

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: The region is delimited by $y=1$, so it's over not under the parabola.

Comment: @p.s. I'm sorry, I have made a typo. The correct equation of the line is y=-1.